# Angular form template

Tags: angularjs, forms, single-page-application

I have been playing around with Angular for a project I am doing for a small rowing club - learning by doing style. I have followed the free codeschool Angular course.

The project is a SPA with a page to manage members. Here I have a Angular-ui typeahead autocompleter to search for members, and it works great.

For another page I would like a page for planing trips and here I would like there be a predefined form. Ideally you select a boat and a form generates with input fields, with the number of people the boat can carry, for each of the fields.

I have been googling for a while and I found no solution for my problem. How do I setup a template that generates a form with the autocompleter in it.

If this type of question have beens asked before I do apologize and hope someone would point me in the right direction.

Comment: It would be good to include some code showing what you have already tried.  If you are looking to load a template at a certain route, use routeProvider's `.when()` function

Comment: I did not include code since i would like to do it myself. I am not looking for someone to write the code for me. I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction :)

Comment: `ng-include` is probably what you're looking for.